DNS server bind9 can not be accessed from external network, but seems to work properly in LAN
I try to set up a DNS on my home server to provide some readable addresses for other computers outside of my home LAN. I think I was able to install and set up bind9 server, at least I get a proper IP with dig, but only when I try to do it in my home LAN network, when I try to access my DNS from outside, the DNS does not respond. I would like to ask an advice in making the DNS visible also outside of my network.
Below are the details of what I would like to do, and what I already have done.
I use a dynamic DNS for my home server that provides a 3rd level domain, let’s say it is myserver.exampledyndns.com and the server's address in the local network is XX.XX.XX.XX. I would like to be able to asses names like pc1.myserver.exampledyndns.com,  pc2.myserver.exampledyndns.com, etc. for some computer outside of my home network. I installed bind9 and here are the configuration files for it
named.conf.options
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
        // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
        // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

        // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable
        // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.
        // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing
        // the all-0's placeholder.

         forwarders {
                8.8.8.8;
                8.8.4.4;
         };

        //=====================================================================>
        // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
// you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
        //=====================================================================>
    dnssec-validation no;

//    listen-on-v6 port 53 {any;};

    listen-on port 53 {any;};

    auth-nxdomain yes;            # conform to RFC1035
    allow-query { any; };         # allow anyone to issue queries
    allow-recursion { any; };
    allow-query-cache { any; };
    recursion no;                 # disallow recursive queries
};

named.conf.local
zone "myserver.exampledyndns.com" in{
   type master;
   file "/var/lib/bind/db.myserver.exampledyndns.com ";
};

*/var/lib/bind/db.myserver.exampledyndns.com *
GNU nano 6.2              /var/lib/bind/db.myserver.exampledyndns.com             
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800 ;
@       IN      SOA     myserver.exampledyndns.com. root.localhost. (
                     2403310917         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns.myserver.exampledyndns.com .
ns      IN      A       YY.YY.YY.YY
pc1  IN      A       YY.YY.YY.YY

resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 127.0.0.53
search wlan  myserver.exampledyndns.com
options edns0 trust-ad
search  myserver.exampledyndns.com
domain  myserver.exampledyndns.com

the port 53 is open in ufw for both tcp and udp. The server stays behind the router, and on router I have port 53 forwarded from WAN to port 53 of the server (NAT loopback disabled)
When inside my LAN I do
dig @XX.XX.XX.XX  pc1.myserver.exampledyndns.com +short
I get YY.YY.YY.YY address, as I would like to get. However, if I will do
dig @myserver.exampledyndns.com  pc1.myserver.exampledyndns.com +short
I do not get anything. If I will allow NAT loopback on the router, then inside LAN
dig @myserver.exampledyndns.com  pc1.myserver.exampledyndns.com +short
also returns YY.YY.YY.YY address.
Outside my LAN I can not get anything.
My question is: what did I do wrong that my DNS does not work outside the LAN?
Thank you in advance for any help or advice.

Is DNS query traffic even reaching your network boundary (your router) from the outside? Enable monitor mode on your router/firewall to check

moreover it speaks to me that this is a home and end-user computing questions due the use of 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4 forward setup. don't do that let bind do it's job

@ChrisDavies thank you for your comment, I checked the settings of the internet provider and it turned out that they block all the incoming traffic on port 53.

It feels that my issue was coming from the provider's firewall settings. According to the description they have on their web pages

For fixed broadband connections, IP traffic from the public network to the connection is restricted. The restrictions correspond to e.g. Regulations of the Communications Regulatory Authority. The restrictions do not eliminate the need for information security services, such as firewall and anti-virus software. Traffic is restricted as follows:
Blocked ports (IPv4 and IPv6)
 25 UL (TCP)
 53 DL (UDP)
 7547 UL/DL (TCP)
 1900 DL (UDP)

Above, UL means traffic from the terminal to the Internet, and DL means traffic from the Internet to the terminal.

So it feels, that I just can not do it like I planned initially.

That usually means it's a consumer connection and they don't want it used for hosting business traffic or more likely malware.

welcome Ivan, remember that you need to accept your answer please. Else we will be reminded until the end of the universe to solve this problem
